# MongoDB Atlas/Cloud retrieving data from _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a project with MongoDB Atlas/Cloud and I have the method to obtain ALL the data of a database that I have created from the cloud.

This is how I did it:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // http://localhost:3000/data
    client.connect(async err => {
        if (await err) {
            console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB Cloud:\n\t" + err.toString());
        }
        console.log("Connected to the DB!");
        const collectionData = client.db("myDatabase").collection("data");

        try {
            const data = await collectionData.find().toArray();
            console.log(data);
            res.json(data);
        } catch (e) {
            res.json({message: e});
        }

        await client.close();
    });
});
```

But I would like to be able to collect each data individually by introducing its _id in the URI. This is how I tried to do it:

```
router.get('/:dataID', (req, res) => {
    // http://localhost:3000/data/<ID>
    client.connect(async err => {
        if (await err) {
            console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB Cloud:\n\t" + err.toString());
        }
        console.log("Connected to the DB!");
        const collectionData = client.db("myDatabase").collection("data");

        try {
            console.log(req.params.dataID); // It works, it prints the _id
            const specificData = await collectionData.findById(req.params.dataID).toArray();
            console.log(specificData);
            res.json(specificData);
        } catch (e) {
            res.json({message: e});
        }

        await client.close();
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. I'm retrieving a blank object: `message: {}`. I've checked the _id introduced, it's exactly the same as the _id from the mongoDB object that I'm trying to retrieve. What am I doing wrong? It should be the `const specificData = await collectionData.findById(req.params.dataID).toArray();` but I don't know what to change to make it work right.

P.S.: After making a GET petition to the server to `/data`, I get the data, but if I try to make another petition after that, I get an MongoDB Error, do anyone know why is this happening? Thank you in advance

Comment: Am I reading it right that you connect to atlas on each http request? Mongo manages a pool of connections, don't multiply them beyond necessity. Connect once on server start or on first query to mongo. The blank object  `message: {}` suggests it comes from catch(e) and the error object is serialised into JSON as an empty one. Try to `console.log(e)` before that.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize this, because it was causing me quite a few problems (both speed and jumping errors like "why is this happening if it didn't happen before?"). It's exactly what the error was not printing: `TypeError: collectionData.findById is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
const specificData = await collectionData.find(req.params.dataID).toArray();
console.log(specificData.get[0]);
```